# Preencher DropDowList com dados de outra tela

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dropdown

tenho uma tela de fuso horário onde tenho os campos nome do fuso horário, utc e horário de verão apenas, esta funcionando direitinho. só que tenho q criar outra tela "período do fuso horário" com três campos o nome do fuso horário já cadastrado e a data de inicio e fim. Não estou conseguindo trazer o nome do fuso horário para meu drodowlist. gostaria uma ajuda pf

Comment: Deixe mais claro sua pergunta e com algumas partes do seu código, para melhor entendimento.

Comment: No construtor da nova janela, adiciona um parâmetro para receber o que queres passar, quando crias a nova janela na class onde tens os dados, passas o que queres por parâmetro e ai já tens acesso aos dados do outro lado

Comment: Esses dados da primeira tela são salvos no banco de dados? Poste o codigo de sua view e do controller para ficar mais facil resolver.